# In Ruby on Rails, when a before_filter is used, then the local variables need to become instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

If we have a before filter that's called `initialize` to initialize common variables, then those variables must be made into instance variables?  Are there alternative ways of doing it?

**Update:** The situation is to validate some URL params, and set them.  This used to be in one action, so everything can be done using local variables.  But now, 3 actions essentially take the same params, so the code is moved to a private method `validate_params`, and called by using `before_filter`, but those local variables seem to have to be made into instance variables.

Can they be not made into instance variables?  Are there frameworks / gems for validating URL params since the built-in validations are for Models.

Comment: Don't call your before filter `initialize`, as that's the name of a method Ruby uses to do other things. Calling your method by that name is likely to stop some other, more important initialisation being completed

Comment: You should also accept more answers if you want anyone to answer your questions.

Comment: Who downvoted this? Seems like a perfectly valid question. Just because someone doesn't accept answers (which they absolutely should) doesn't mean their questions should be downvoted if they're on topic and understandable.

Comment: don't know if it affects Rails 3.  wonder why Rails's `initialize` is not renamed `_internal_initialize` or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

*Are there alternative ways of doing it?*

Doing what, exactly? If you want a variable to be available to methods in the controller, then an instance variable would typically be appropriate. If you want to have a variable (or more likely a constant) available to all controllers, or to models and views, there are other techniques to accomplish that. We'll need more detail about the specific requirements to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables initialized whenever you get a new instance of an object, you can override the initialize *method* instead of using a callback:

```
class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sauce

  def initialize(*args)
    @sauce ||= 'tomato'
    super(*args)
  end
end
```

Just don't forget to call `super` since ActiveRecords do a bunch of other stuff on initialization.